# React Native Stop Pan Gesture during Move

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to stop the `PanResponder` system while it's still moving. i.e. if a condition is met, cancel or end the gesture.

I have an `Animated.Value` connected to the gesture and a listener on that value. If it is greater than 100, I'd like to suspend the pan gesture.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop a `PanReponder` system by enabling the `PanResponder` on the parent view.

From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system), we have:

> onStartShouldSetResponder and onMoveShouldSetResponder are called with
>   a bubbling pattern, where the deepest node is called first. That means
>   that the deepest component will become responder when multiple Views
>   return true for *ShouldSetResponder handlers. This is desirable in
>   most cases, because it makes sure all controls and buttons are usable.
>
> However, sometimes a parent will want to make sure that it becomes
>   responder. This can be handled by using the capture phase. Before the
>   responder system bubbles up from the deepest component, it will do a
>   capture phase, firing on*ShouldSetResponderCapture. So if a parent
>   View wants to prevent the child from becoming responder on a touch
>   start, it should have a onStartShouldSetResponderCapture handler which
>   returns true.

In your case, you should set the onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture for the parent view, when your condition is met.

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => this.isMyConditionTrue(),
```

AND, also set the following attribute on the child responder:

```
onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
```

in order to allow the parent to capture the responder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false in `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` to stop `PanResponder`. Consider following example:

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  {...}
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => {
    if (stopPanResponder) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  {...}
  onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true
});
```